# "continue" keyword inside "if" and "while" loop

Tags: python, while-loop, continue

I'm learning Python. My goal is to print out 1 through 5, skipping 3, using a while loop, if statement, and keyword `continue`. My code below prints out just 1 2, and not 1 2 4 5.

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    if i == 3:
        continue
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

1. Why does this loop stop when `i == 3`, rather than skipping 3 and continuing with `i = 4` and `i = 5`?
2. How would you correct this code so that it prints 1 2 4 5 (continuing/skipping 3)?

Comment: it doesn't stop, it simply can't move forward because you always skip the `i += 1` and the value of `i` never increases after it reaches `3`

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop for this task? In your own words, what causes the value of `i` to change in your code? If the `continue` happens, will `i` be updated? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you reach 3 the program will never increase `i` anymore and will loop forever

You could increment before the test:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
    i += 1
    if i == 3:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Comment: You have an off-by-one error: `i <= 5` should be `i <= 4`. But IMHO, that makes the loop range hard to read cause instead of *1-5* it's *(0-4)+1*.

Comment: ... Or you could do `i < 5`

Comment: Thank you @mozway for your explanation. I selected your answer because it preserves the use of the while loop, continue keyword, and i +=1 increment which were part of the exercise I was working on.

Comment: @Cuadros I think I already explained, once you reach 3, you continue the loop but skipping the incrementation, thus you loop forever staying at 3

Answer (score 3):

To fix this you can do it like this, print the value when it is not three and then you don't even need to use `continue`:

```py
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    if i != 3:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

However, a faster and easier solution would be this:

```py
for i in range(1, 5 + 1):
    if i != 3:
        print(i)
```

Or in the `for` loop case it would be possible to use `continue` because the for loop will continue to the next element:

```py
for i in range(1, 5 + 1):
    if i == 3:
        continue
    print(i)
```

And just because, but you can also use a short (linewise) (and fast too) solution like this one:

```py
print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 5 + 1) if i != 3))
```

Comment: Hehe if you want to do the range idea a janky/funny way without a loop would be: `print(*filter((3).__ne__, range(1,6)), sep='\n')`

Comment: @jab Don't call dunder methods directly. You could use a generator expression instead: `*(i for i in range(1, 6) if i!=3)`.

Comment: You don't need an explicit `join(str())` since `print()` can do it for you: `print(*(i for i in range(1, 5+1) if i!=3), sep='\n')`

Comment: I mean I do believe that calling the dunder method once is technically faster than performing a lookup on each iteration.

Comment: @wjandrea I think that it was meant just as a _possible_ and extremely short solution just because it is possible, normally it wouldn't be used (I think), also yes, I understand the unpacking but for some reason I don't like doing it, possibly because something about memory usage, maybe I have a misconception about it

Comment: @wjandrea also the `for loop` markdown was intentional as to group a concept together

Comment: @Matiiss I thought that was what you were going for, but the word `loop` isn't code, so shouldn't be formatted as code. You could use bold instead: **`for` loop**

Comment: @wjandrea: I'm okay with using the dunders specifically for `map`/`filter` in some cases (read: Actually profiled and need the performance and you know the dunder well enough to be sure it's safe), but yeah, it's not just ugly, it's brittle. In this case, it's safe, but if the iterable is some non-`int` numeric type, you'd misbehave when `int.__ne__` returned `NotImplemented` (treated as `True`, though it'll become a `TypeError` to use it in a boolean context at some point). Examples where it would misbehave include `3.0` and `Decimal(3)`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `continue`, the increment will be skipped and `i` will be stuck at 3 forever

Comment: So how do you fix it?

Comment: Other answers have already provided several ways to fix it, so check them out to get some inspiration and/or fixes

Answer (score 1):

Your loop doesn't stop once you hit 3, rather it continues indefinitely as you always skip incrementing `i` once the value of `i` reaches 3.

You need to do something in your `if` block before you `continue` to ensure you don't get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop, when you reach `i == 3`, you want to skip it, and you do it by using `continue`.
`continue` means going back to the `while` condition and evaluating it.

Because you didn't increment `i`, the statement will always be true (always less than 5), but because you didn't change `i`, the `if` condition will also be always true. And your code loops inifintely.

You need to change the value of `i` before `continue` in the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck in an infinite loop. When you `continue`, you never increment `i`, so it stays 3 forever.

Comment: So how do you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Because `continue` makes you not fulfill the rest of your code. Therefore, you just have an infinite loop. You can see that if you run

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    if i == 3:
        print(i)
        continue
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

If you want to do this in this method, you can just increment i before your continue, i.e.

```
i = 1
while i <= 5:
    if i == 3:
        i+=1
        continue
    print(i)
    i += 1
```